# React: How to get intellisense for stylesheet object in VS Code?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

Let's say that I have a component in react like this...

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>
```

...to style it, I can use an inline notation...

```
<h1 style={{ fontSize: 32, color: 'dodgerblue' }}>Hello World</h1>
```

...or I can encapsulate the styles inside an object like this...

```
const style = {
  fontSize: 32,
  color: 'dodgerblue'
}

<h1 style={style}>Hello World</h1>
```

...the problem with the second approach is that I am longer getting IntelliSense or proper error-handling for the stylesheet. In react-native, we can do something like this...

```
const style = Stylesheet.create({
  ...
})
```

...I hope I've explained it enough, so can we do something similar in React?

Comment: Use typing, even JSDoc is a solution

Comment: you probably want to use Typescript. Runtime errors check for style in web is very vague AFAIK

Comment: In typescript, I do get errors, but no luck with CSS IntelliSense.

Comment: Is there any functionality in React itself, that does the hard work for us?

Comment: You probably can do something like `const style: DivStyle = { /*react inline style inside*/}`. These is something  i had used in the past. It highly depends on what framework you are using. But you get the idea. And you can even do something like `interface myowninputstyle extends InputStyle {}`

Comment: Sorry, but is the DivStyle a separate interface I should make, or does it come with react?